# ReactNative : Native module SQLite tried to override SQLitePlugin.check the getPackage() method

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a working Android react native app ( react native v 0.60.5 ). I tried to use Sqlite storage in my apps but show this error

[image]

build.gradle: 
  implementation project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')

```
 MainApplication.js file
    import org.pgsqlite.SQLitePluginPackage;
    @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
           packages.add(new SQLitePluginPackage());
           return packages;
        }
```

Setting.gradle

```
include ':react-native-sqlite-storage'
project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/src/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AfblSellsApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-magic-move": "^0.6.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.3",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.9.4",
    "react-native-svg-uri": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.4.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

> How Can I solve this my problem

Answer (score 1):

My android/settings.gradle is

```
rootProject.name = 'Awesomeproject'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':react-native-sqlite-storage'
project(':react-native-sqlite-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android')
include ':app'
```

and Nothing is changed in android\app\src\main\java\com\awesomeproject\MainApplication.java

And it works!